# Converting String to Integer fails

Tags: python, pyspark

I am trying to convert a string column of a csv file into an integer or float type using pyspark. Everytime I convert it, the output of the conversion is "null".

When I try to check if the string contains a number it says "false.
How can I convert the string?

THis is my try to solve this.[Shoprt pic of the data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3rOqU.png)

`w=weather.withColumn("Temperature",col("Temperature").cast('int'))

w.printSchema()
`

Comment: You do realize that the column values aren't valid numbers?

Comment: strip the `°F` from the string.

Comment: @EdoAkse does not help really...

Answer (score 0):

The issue is the value in your "Temperature" column is `26 °F`, this value can of course not be casted to an int, because only the first 2 characters of the string are integers. You need a way to retrieve only the first integer characters of this string. I'd say there are 2 options, splitting the value on " " and get the first item or use regex.

For this example I'm going to use the splitting, while not the most robust, you can try the regex out yourself.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

w = weather.withColumn("Temperature",F.split(col("Temperature"), " ").getItem(0).cast('int'))
```

Comment: When I do this, and I do w.select(Temperature").show(), the output is "null" again.

Comment: And when I do "w.printSchema() " at "Temperature" it says integer. Thats confusing me

Comment: You can try casting a string which is an invalid to int, the schema will say you casted it to an int so the column type will be an int, that does not mean that there is an actual value in it. 
Otherwise you can try this: `weather.withColumn("Temperature",F. regexp_extract(col("Temperature"), "\d*", 1).cast('int'))`. If this doesn't work try to change some stuff yourself, "doesn't work" does not help us at all. Here's the documentation: https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.2/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.regexp_extract.html

Comment: But how can this be possible that ther is no value in it? I am just learning and getting into this python stuff so sorry for any convenience.

Comment: Well, lets say you try casting "Hello" to an int. The column will think the value it contains is an int, so that's what the schema says. But since "Hello" isn't an integer, the value after casting will be null.

Comment: Ahhh. Okay makes sense to me. But how can a number not be an integer value, even if it is in a string?

Comment: Well, you need to tell python what part of a string you want to convert to the integer value. If I try to cast "18 F, 17 C" to an int, how would python ever know which part of the string you want to be the integer? Would it be 18, 17 or 1817?